# Is it possible to generate java test stub files from cucumber gherkin feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, gherkin, cucumber-jvm

Instead of reading the feature file, writing the name of the methods, add the right annotations and variables I want to "compile" the feature file and generate the java test file automatically.

Is it possible? Do you know of a tool that can do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you run Cucumber-JVM it will generate snippets for each undefined step. You can cut and paste these into a class of your choosing.

Running inside IntelliJ you can use Alt-Return to generate a definition for a step. There are plugins for Eclipse that do this too, but I haven't used them recently.

Comment: Thanks! It's not working in IntelliJ Community Edition :( But I can run the tests and see the undefined step. It only shows the last step, is there a way to see all the missing steps?

Comment: Sorry - in the middle of something. But you can try this from the command prompt (which should print out all the snippets):      mvn clean test

Answer (score 0):

you can set `dryRun=true` which should show you all missing steps.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(  monochrome = true,
                         tags = "@tags",
                     features = "src/test/resources/features/",
                       format = { "pretty","html: cucumber-html-reports",
                                  "json: cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" },
                        dryRun = true,
                         glue = "glue_code_folder" )

public class RunCucumber_Test {
  //Run this
}
```